# Matlab ezmesh - plotting a plane that is a function of one variable

Tags: matlab

I'm plotting planes in matlab using ezmesh. Everything goes fine until I attempt to plot a plane such as z=y -- ezmesh wants a function of two variables. I'd like to continue using ezmesh in my code rather than using something like surf for this one plane... can ezmesh plot this plane?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works over here:

```
ezmesh(@(x,y)y)
```

The equation `z=y` acutally *is* a function of two variables, only it holds for all `x`, which is expressed by not using `x`.

Comment: Ok I see that does work. However I'm using the solve function to produce the equation of a plane, and in this case its outputting a function z = y, which I believe matlab thinks is equivalent to @(y)y. Do you know how I take func=@(y)y and turn it into func=@(x,y)=y so that ezmesh will accept it?

Comment: @Brian: You can make a small wrapper: `z=@(y)y; z2=@(x,y)z(y);` and then use `ezmesh(z2)`, or all in one go: `ezmesh(@(x,y)z(y))`

Comment: Thanks Rody -- I'm able to get all of this to work, but for some reason when I let the solve function produce the function z rather than declaring it myself and then use ezmesh(@(x,y)z(y) -- z is the function handle -- I get the error "Index must be a positive integer or logical."

Comment: @Brian: I'm guessing you're using symbolic math?

Comment: Yes, I'm using symbolic math.

Comment: @Brian: OK, well then you can use `z = matlabFunction(z);` which results in `z = @(y)y`, which you can then wrap as above. Does that work?